# Android studio missing SDK Manager after update

Tags: android-studio

After updating android studio I am missing my SDK manager icon. Right now I am using version 2.2.1. In system settings I could not find Android SDK tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the SDK manager this way:
https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#sdk-manager

Comment: In the system settings I could not find Android SDK tab.

Comment: It is on Tools > Android > SDK Manager